# Can't find MAMP Pro 2.1.1 database files

Tags: mysql, mamp

I have a mac running OSX 10.9.5 and MAMP installed and recently installed the trial version of MAMP Pro 2.1.1.  During the trial I used MAMP Pro and not MAMP. The trial has now expired. MAMP Pro is still installed.

When I now go and run MAMP and look at my databases and sites created using MAMP Pro I can't run the sites or find the databases created whilst using MAMP Pro.  I assumed they were in the same place as MAMP.  Not so.

I found this thread http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=7416  but it talks about an earlier version of MAMP Pro 1.7.2 and when looking in the //Library/Application Support/ folder cannot find "appsolute" or MAMP.

Can anyone shed some light as to where MAMP Pro might be hiding the database files so I can copy them back to MAMP?

**SOLVED**

When using Finder on the mac and viewing the Library I could not see the appsolute folder under Application Support.  However using Parallel8 and Windows explorer looking at the Mac Disk I could see Z:\Library\Application Support\appsolute.  So I could copy the database folders across to MAMP's mysql data folder.  Make sure you copy the mysql folder and the following files:

ib_data1
ib_logfile1
ib_logfile0

P.S.  of course back up the orginal MAMP DB files and folders beforehand so you can recover it it all goes pear shape.